# Google Sign-In for Website - Login State Management

Tags: javascript, php, session, google-signin, google-identity

I'm incorporating Google Sign-In for my website and the basic setup is working fine, however I face a problem to manage the user's login status.

I came across the below SO question, which suggested to use sessionStorage/localStorage to carry the login status across pages of a website, and when user signs out the stored info should be cleared.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/40206395/5345604

I afraid I don't entirely understand the suggested implementation though. What if user signs out from his Google account somewhere else, say from Gmail or from Google Maps? In this case when the user revisits my website, how can I detect that he is no longer signed in with Google and remove the stored client side session? Or this is not the way it is supposed to work?

And on top of the above question, I'm also thinking about the authentication with my backend (PHP). Given the ID token, shall I be sending it across to my server and authenticate it with the Google API Client Library every time? Or shall I only authenticate the user once and store a flag of indication in $_SESSION, and then destroy the session when the user signs out? (Given that the token is in fact a JWT, I suppose the implementation is meant to be stateless and requires the token to be passed to the server every time? Are there any concerns to implement it with the traditional approach of a server side session?)

Answer (score 0):

I can only answer your first question: The login of your website is completely separate from the login status of other Google services. Even YouTube is separate from google.com.