# Google Login Integration: How to make sure that the users could not access any page of the website without logging in?

Tags: javascript, google-signin

I'm working on a website with at least 50 pages. I'm trying to integrate Google login feature in the website. I have a login page made up. I want the users to first login using their google accounts and then be able to see the content on the website.

For example:

If users know or have bookmarked a page, say, www.example.com/qouebrj and if they are not logged in, the user must be redirected to the google login page (say www.example.com/login-or-signup) or there should be a pop up with google login option and the rest of the background blurred (like that in quora's website).

**I'm working with Javascript based technologies to build front end and back end and mySQL DB.**

Any help would be deeply appreciated!

Comment: I think this will help you... https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38083568/how-to-check-if-user-is-logged-in-or-not-with-google-sign-in-oauth-2-0