# Is there a way to identify a Google user that is unique and private to them?

Tags: javascript, google-oauth

I am building a simple web app which uses Google OAuth2 to get users to sign in and am wondering if their is some way to uniquely identify a Google user (like a user ID) that is also private to the Google user (like a password).

Comment: Please share the code you've written so that we have something to start from in understanding your question.

Comment: What do you mean with private? If it's private then the server will not disclose it. Do you mean an ID that's unique universally and not only among Google accounts?

Comment: What I essentially want is some way to make sure the user is who they say they are on every page of my site, not just the sign in page when using Google sign in with Javascript

Answer (score 0):

In short: no.

I was trying to make sure a user was signed in on all pages. [This](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50256404/10286818) answer showed me how to do that.