# How can I check if the user is logged into their Google account with Google One Tap?

Tags: javascript, google-api, google-api-client, google-api-javascript-client

My question is here ([How to check if user is logged in or not with "Google Sign In" (OAuth 2.0)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38083568/how-to-check-if-user-is-logged-in-or-not-with-google-sign-in-oauth-2-0) ), but the relevant package has been deprecated (https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/web/people).

I am using [Google One Tap](https://developers.google.com/identity/gsi/web/reference/js-reference) in my project. How do I know if the user is logged into their Google account or not with Google One Tap.

Answer (score 0):

I asked Google Bard and I think it gave a good answer.

There are a few ways to check if a user is logged in to Google.

- **Check the user's session storage.** The user's session storage will contain a key for the user's Google ID if they are logged in. You can check this key to see if the user is logged in.
- **Use the Google Sign In API.** The Google Sign In API provides a way to check if a user is logged in. You can use this API to get the user's Google ID and other information about their account.
- **Check the user's browser cookies.** The user's browser cookies will contain a cookie for the Google Sign In service if they are logged in. You can check this cookie to see if the user is logged in.

Here is an example of how to check if a user is logged in using the Google Sign In API:

```
const googleSignIn = require('google-signin');

const auth2 = googleSignIn.build();

const isSignedIn = await auth2.isSignedIn();

if (isSignedIn) {
  // The user is logged in.
  const user = await auth2.currentUser();

  // Do something with the user's information.
} else {
  // The user is not logged in.
}
```

With google one tap package :

```
const googleOneTap = require('google-one-tap');

const auth2 = googleOneTap.build();

const isSignedIn = await auth2.isSignedIn();

if (isSignedIn) {
  // The user is logged in.
  const user = await auth2.currentUser();

  // Do something with the user's information.
} else {
  // The user is not logged in.
}
```

In addition, it is possible to access other information of the user through these two packages. If you need a different solution, you can use Google Bard.